# ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher [req-xxxxx] Exception during message handling: 'metadata'

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I installed Openstack(Kilo) on Centos7

The error occurred in adding the security group rules

I'm using Nova-network.

I got this error form nova-compute.log

```
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher [req-76584058-8dbd-4860-a048-e9dbad712779 843c47b4a71b4ac3a6c4375d558aa423 3f4e979ea9b9409a9425442a8b096457 - -
-] Exception during message handling: 'metadata'
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback))
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     executor_callback)
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     result = func(ctxt, **new_args)
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 6716, in refresh_instance_security_rules
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return self.manager.refresh_instance_security_rules(ctxt, instance)
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 434, in decorated_function
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     args = (_load_instance(args[0]),) + args[1:]
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 425, in _load_instance
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     expected_attrs=metas)
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/objects/instance.py", line 492, in _from_db_object
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     instance['metadata'] = utils.instance_meta(db_inst)
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/utils.py", line 816, in instance_meta
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     if isinstance(instance['metadata'], dict):
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher KeyError: 'metadata'
2015-07-31 16:55:05.669 5950 TRACE oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher
```

Thank you warm-hearted!

Answer (score 1):

Although it's been 4 years, probably nobody even cares what the root cause is but I put it here anyway, since I did some (re)search.

> The object_compat decorator expects to get the Instance object with
>   'metadata' and 'system_metadata' attributes but if those aren't in the
>   db instance dict object, Instance._from_db_object will fail with a
>   KeyError.
>
> In Kilo this happens per refresh_instance_security_rules because in
>   the compute API code, the instance passed to
>   refresh_instance_security_rules comes from the call to get the
>   security group(s) which joins on the instances column, but that
>   doesn't join on the metadata/system_metadata fields for the instances.
>   So when the instances get to object_compat in the compute manager and
>   the db instance dict is converted to the Instance object, it expects
>   fields that aren't in the dict and we get the KeyError.

Refer to the following code commit for details.

https://opendev.org/openstack/nova/commit/9369aab04e37b7818d49b00e65857be8b3564e9e

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error.

Try adding the rules to the security group first and then create the instance.
It worked for me.

This is a work around only. Since I don't have enough privileges to comment I am adding this as an answer.

If I get to know about any solution I will post it here.